# Convert a unified string to dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I'm looking for the way to convert string data that looks like the following:

```py
"Kyiv, region A, 123\nKyiv, region B, 456\nKyiv, region C, 789\nPoltava, region D, 321\nPoltava, region E, 876\nPoltava, region F, 654"
```

to a 'dict' with two keys

```py
{'city':'Kiev', 'population': 123}
```

I can convert substrings of the original string to lists of strings in this format:

```
[['Kyiv', 'region A', 123'], ['Kyiv', 'region B', '456'],] ...
```

but can't proceed further.

Could somebody help me parse this string?

This is the code I have so far:

```
dic_city = {}

cities = []
population = []

cities = [a.split(',') for a in s.split('\n')]

print(cities)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think the dict should also have city as Kyiv?. Also, I guess you would also require to have region within the dict to have a separation amongst the city else it would be to increment population when ever the same city is encountered?

Comment: Thank you!
It should have keys {'city': Kiev, 'population': 111}, {'city': Poltava, 'population': 222}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt = "Kyiv, region A, 123\nKyiv, region B, 456\nKyiv, region C, 789\nPoltava, region D, 321\nPoltava, region E, 876\nPoltava, region F, 654"

d = {}
for x in txt.splitlines():
  city = x.split(',')[0]
  if d.get(city):
    d[city] += int(x.split(',')[2]) # same city then add population
  else:
    d[city] = int(x.split(',')[2]) # different city add new key to dictionary

print(d)
```

Output -

```
{'Kyiv': 1368, 'Poltava': 1851}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the data by newline to get each entry, and then split by comma + space to get the city name and population from each entry:

```py
entries = data.split("\n")
result = []
for entry in entries:
    city, _, pop = entry.split(", ")
    result.append(dict(city=city, population=population))
    
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {'city': 'Kyiv', 'population': '123'},
 {'city': 'Kyiv', 'population': '456'},
 {'city': 'Kyiv', 'population': '789'},
 {'city': 'Poltava', 'population': '321'},
 {'city': 'Poltava', 'population': '876'},
 {'city': 'Poltava', 'population': '654'}
]
```